# Calling setContentView from another Class

Tags: android

I have ActivityA which creates a ClassB object wherein I pass a context like below:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB(ActivityA.this);
```

I want to have a method in ClassB where in I can call ActivityA's

`setContentView(R.layout.sample);`

Is this possible or anyway to do this?

ClassB is where I inflate my custom dialog.

Edited: Reason for this is I want to refresh ActivityA's view bec. I'm setting a Locale.

Comment: Any specific reason for calling Activity's setContentView() in ClassB?

Answer (score 1):

> ClassB is where I inflate my custom dialog.

Create dialog like,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
dialog.show();
```